# One project with different Teams and backlogs

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-boards

In my org, I have 4 teams and each of them will have their own backlog and will plan their sprints based on this. We want to have a main backlog where the product owners will discuss what work items will go into their backlogs

I would like some guidance as to what is the best practice to use Area path and iteration path to allow the different teams to plan based on their own backlog but also have a Mother of allboards for the POs to discuss and put it under the different teams.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: Hi  Vito Liu-MSFT, we are still testing out ways to work.. it would be greatly appreciated if you had examples of how we can organize our backlogs

Comment: Hi @Rakavy, you could check my answer and then kindly share the result here. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Rakavy, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: Hi @Vito Liu-MSFT, we followed the approach you mentioned and will be trying it out. so far it seems to be okay. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like some guidance as to what is the best practice to use Area path and iteration path to allow the different teams to plan based on their own backlog but also have a Mother of allboards for the POs to discuss and put it under the different teams.

In the Azure DevOps boards, it has default area path, if we create another teams, it will create a sub area area path under the default area path.

In my project the default team is `test` and I create teams `test01` and `test02`, open project settings->Team configuration->Areas, we could see the `test team` area path is `test`, `test01` area path is `test\test01` and tesst02 area path is `test\test02`, switch team to `test` and click the button **include sub-areas**, check the pic below

[image]

Now we could see `test01` and `test02` teams work items in the `test team` backlog, we could create work item in the test team, and POs could discuss and change the area path to put it under the different teams. You could check the gif below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is detailed documentation to work with multiple teams. You can adapt some practics in your process:

1. [Plans (Agile at scale)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/plans/?view=azure-devops)
2. [How SAFe concepts map to Azure Boards artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/plans/safe-concepts?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process)
3. [Configure Azure Boards to support SAFe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/plans/safe-configure-boards?view=azure-devops)
4. [Agile culture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/plans/agile-culture?view=azure-devops#horizontal-vs-vertical)

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned 'Sprints', 'Product Owner' - I feel Scrum framework would be the best agile method. Product Owner has the final say on what goes on the 'Main Backlog'. When planning a Sprint, I expect you are going to involve all 4 teams. Azure is the best tool to maintaining and delivering backlogs.

For POs and mother of all boards you may have to rely upon a different tool like Asana.

Thanks